# Flutter - GetX - Changing theme needs hot reload when using Get.theme

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

When changing theme to Darkmode with GetX via Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.dark), most widgets change accordingly. But those widgets using some parameter with Get.theme need a hot reload for the effect to take place.

As a comment suggested [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/491), that is because Get.theme is immutable. Using the extension method context.theme does resolve the issue, however, I do not always have access to a context. Get.context.theme does not resolve the issue. What should I do in this case? Since passing the context to wherever needed kinda defeats the purpose of using GetX.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what 'some parameters' you are talking about since you didn't include any code, but you can use the `Get.changeTheme()` method which takes a `ThemeData` object and changes the theme accordingly without hot restart.